# Create a custom gateway - model-problems

Tags: php, payum

i'm trying to create a custom gateway and have followed a lot of the different documentations. Yesterday i discovered the new Payum/Skeleton and started with that and followed that example.
Though i have a problem when redirected to the capture-page, i get the following two exceptions:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Payum\Core\Exception\RequestNotSupportedException' with message
>   'Request Capture{model: Identity} is not supported. Make sure the
>   storage extension for "Payum\Core\Model\Payment" is registered to the
>   gateway. Make sure the storage find method returns an instance by id
>   "5678ff3e481ba". Make sure the gateway supports the requests and there
>   is an action which supports this request (The method returns true).
>   There may be a bug, so look for a related issue on the issue tracker.'
>   in /home/vagrant/code/payumdibs/vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/Exception/RequestNotSupportedException.php
>   on line 57

And

> Payum\Core\Exception\RequestNotSupportedException: Request
>   Capture{model: Identity} is not supported. Make sure the storage
>   extension for "Payum\Core\Model\Payment" is registered to the gateway.
>   Make sure the storage find method returns an instance by id
>   "5678ff3e481ba". Make sure the gateway supports the requests and there
>   is an action which supports this request (The method returns true).
>   There may be a bug, so look for a related issue on the issue tracker.
>   in
>   /home/vagrant/code/payumdibs/vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/Exception/RequestNotSupportedException.php
>   on line 57

I've used x-debug and figured out that when CaptureAction::supports is called $request->getModel() is not an instance of \ArrayAccess and therefore returns false.

When using the standard payment gateways everything works fine, but using a custom does not.

My config:

```
$payum = (new PayumBuilder())
        ->addDefaultStorages()
        ->addGatewayFactory('paypal', new \Acme\Paypal\PaypalGatewayFactory([]))
        ->addGateway('offline', [
            'factory' => 'offline',
        ])->addGateway('paypal', [
            'factory' => 'paypal',
            'sandbox' => true,
        ])->getPayum();
```

Anyone have any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: Looks like a bug, I'll come back with the solution a bit later.

Comment: please check this issue out, there is a solution 
https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer in comment by Maksim Kotlyar.
https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/452